# Converting a translucent BufferedImage to a Shape object

Tags: java, graphics

I'm facing a problem where I would like to convert a `BufferedImage` to a `Shape` object and exclude all the transparent pixels.

The algorithm I've come up with is quite terrible, but works. I was wondering if anyone knows of a more efficient way to get the same result. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
// O(n^2)
Area a = new Area();
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.setSize(1,1);
for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
    for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
         if(image.getRGB(x,y) >>> 24 > 0){
             r.setLocation(x,y);
             a.add(new Area(r));
         }
return a;
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the original algorithm just to find a point on your shape and then add points by "following" it. Also if you'd like to have fewer points you may think on using some kind of numeric derivative of x over y and add points when a significant change happens.